# Moodle Webservices to Get or Create Course Activities is not working

Tags: rest, web-services, moodle

I have Moodle 3.6 and I have a User Interface which uses API to call functions in Moodle. I used the functions to let the user on the User Interface to create a new course and add activities to it, and it works successfully; however, the user can not create activities in it and can not get the list of activities of this course.

Is there any configuration in Moodle that would be changed to allow user create activities in a course using the rest webservice.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Can you expand on "the user can not create activities in it and can not get the list of activities of this course"? Why can they not do those things?

Comment: Share the code you have tried.